# Insert list items at start of of each item in a list of lists

Tags: dart

I have two lists that are the same length:

```
List<List<String>> list1 = [["John","Omar","Jane"],["Rick","Hulie","Frank"],["Pri","Mary","Tim"]]
 List<int> list2 = [1,5,9]
```

I want to add insert the numbers from list2 to the start of the lists in list1 like this..

list3 to look like

```
 [["1","John","Omar","Jane"],["5", "Rick","Hulie","Frank"],["9","Pri","Mary","Tim"]]
```

Comment: Consider whether you need it to be a list of lists, or whether it could be a list of `Queue`s. Then adding at the front will be cheaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the list and insert each of the numbers at index 0.

```dart
 List<List<String>> list1 = [["John","Omar","Jane"],["Rick","Hulie","Frank"], ["Pri","Mary","Tim"]];
 List<int> list2 = [1,5,9];
 for (int i = 0;i < list1.length;i++) {
   list1[i].insert(0,list2[i].toString());
 }
 
 // if you want a more dart like the solution then use this.
 list1.asMap().forEach((index,value) => value.insert(0,list2[index].toString()));
```

Comment: The "more Dart like" version isn't particularly efficient. It's more functional programming-like, but Dart is both functional and imperative, so the functional approach isn't really "more Dart". I'd prefer the former approach, it's much clearer.

Comment: @Irn Thanks for your explanation. Indeed I also prefer the first approach, I just shared both the approach to let the op decide what he wants to use.